# Error in loading ONNX model with ONNXRuntime

Tags: pytorch, onnx, onnxruntime

I'm converting a customized Pytorch model to ONNX. However, when loading it with ONNXRuntime, I've encountered an error as follows:

```
onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.RuntimeException: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 6 : RUNTIME_EXCEPTION : Exception during initialization: ...onnxruntime/core/providers/cpu/tensor/transpose.h:46 onnxruntime::TransposeBase::TransposeBase(const onnxruntime::OpKernelInfo &) v >= 0 && static_cast<uint64_t>(v) <= std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() was false.
```

I've checked with `onnx.checker.check_model()` and it's totally fine.
I've also tried to replace `transpose()` into `permute()` in `forward()` function but the error has still remained.

Is anyone familiar with this error?

Environments:

```
Python 3.7
Pytorch 1.9.0
CUDA 10.2 
ONNX 1.10.1
ONNXRuntime 1.8.1 
OS Ubuntu 18.04
```

Comment: Can you share the ONNX file?

Comment: @SergiiDymchenko It's here ([onnx file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tQ7XwOJj8XoWuWbTleKEv9Q6v-ESW3kO/view?usp=sharing)). Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `perm` attribute of node `Transpose_52` is [-1, 0, 1] although ONNX Runtime requires that all of them should be positive: https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/c99aa3a3f3834adcbb888ce4b964f2695c524eae/onnxruntime/core/providers/cpu/tensor/transpose.h#L46

Comment: Oh. Thank you a lot. I had thought that we only need to change from `transpose()` to `permute()` and don't need to pay attention to those indices. It makes sense now. Thank you @dkim.

Comment: @dkim Can you post in the term of an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `perm` attribute of node `Transpose_52` is [-1, 0, 1] although ONNX Runtime requires that all of them should be positive: [`onnxruntime/core/providers/cpu/tensor/transpose.h#L46`](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/c99aa3a3f3834adcbb888ce4b964f2695c524eae/onnxruntime/core/providers/cpu/tensor/transpose.h#L46)